# Can't increase value of struct in map

Tags: dictionary, go, struct

I have a struct like this

```
type EPMEmote struct {
    EmoteID   string
    EmoteCode string
    EPM       int64
}
```

inside this map

```
map[string]EPMEmote
```

I can add stuff easily like this:

```
bot.epm[pmsg.Emotes[0].Name] = EPMEmote{
            EmoteCode: pmsg.Emotes[0].Name,
            EmoteID:   pmsg.Emotes[0].ID,
            EPM:       1,
        }
```

but I can't increase the value of EPM when I check beforehand if the value exists

```
_, exists := bot.epm[pmsg.Emotes[0].Name]
    if exists {
        bot.epm[pmsg.Emotes[0].Name].EPM++
    }
```

Why does the compiler throw the error

cannot assign to bot.epm[pmsg.Emotes[0].Name].EPM

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must first assign the struct to a variable, update the value and then store it back in the map again:

```
e, exists := bot.epm[pmsg.Emotes[0].Name]
    if exists {
        e.EPM++
        bot.epm[pmsg.Emotes[0].Name] = e
    }
```

You can find more details here: [Access Struct in Map (without copying)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438253/access-struct-in-map-without-copying)

Comment: ohhh that makes sense! Thank you very much!