# How to update a struct property in a map

Tags: dictionary, go

Currently trying to learn Go.

I have the following function, but it only works when the team doesn't exist in the map already and it creates a new record in the map.  It will not update the values if the team already has a struct in the map.

```
func AddLoss(teamMap map[string]TeamRow, teamName string) {
    if val, ok := teamMap[teamName]; ok {
        val.Wins++
        val.GamesPlayed++
    } else {
        newTeamRow := TeamRow{Losses: 1}

        teamMap[teamName] = newTeamRow
    }
}
```

I have updated the function to just replace the existing record with a brand new struct with the values I want, but that seems odd that I can't update the values in a map.

Can someone explain this to me, or point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean "it only works when the team doesn't exist"?  What happens when it does exist? What exactly is the observed behavior?

Comment: You probably need to use `*TeamRow` rather than `TeamRow`.

Comment: Use *TeamRow as suggested in previous comment or assign the value back to the map.  See [Why do I get a “cannot assign” error when setting value to a struct as a value in a map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32751537/why-do-i-get-a-cannot-assign-error-when-setting-value-to-a-struct-as-a-value-i), [Access Struct in Map (without copying)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438253/access-struct-in-map-without-copying), ...

Comment: @Flimzy The values don't get updated is what is observed.  The object keeps the same property values it was assigned when it was first created.

Comment: @ThunderCat Thank you for the link, that made a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a map of `string` to the value of `TeamRow` so when you get the `val` out of the map it returns the value of the team, not a pointer to the team.  If you make the map a string to the pointer of `TeamRow` then when you get the val out it will point to the memory that is stored in the map so values will persist beyond the scope of your `AddLoss` function.  To do this simply add a `*` to the map declaration - `teamMap map[string]*TeamRow` though when you populate it you will then also need to store pointers in the map.

Comment: Thank you for this!